# differential solid angle

Tags: tikz-pgf

how  can one draw these figures with tikz ?

http://www.seos-project.eu/modules/laser-rs/laser-rs-c03-s02-p02.html

Thank you

GT

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is not very likely that you get an answer like this. Please show at least a little effort (starting with the shift-button) like inserting the code of what you have already tried and putting screen-shots instead of external (pos. unsecure) links. Like the question stands now, it is more a "do my work for me" post, which is not what this site is about. We are volunteers willing to help you with specific problems (the more research character, the more fun for us) but not gratis programmers. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: You can find similar examples in TeXample.net: http://texample.net/tikz/examples/map-projections/, http://texample.net/tikz/examples/spherical-and-cartesian-grids/ You can study them and, after that, make more specific questions here.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You won't get answers if your question looks like "draw it for me"</strike>

So you won't get complete answers at least. Shading the cone and adding labels is up to you. And of course, no explanations and warranties ;)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (2,0) arc (-0:-180:4cm and 2cm)coordinate[pos=0.75] (a);
    \draw[dotted] (2,0) arc (0:180:4cm and 2cm);
    \draw (2,0) arc (0:180:4cm);
    \begin{scope}[rotate around={50:(-2,0)}]
    \draw[shade,fill=gray!40] (1.3,5mm) -- (-2,0) -- (1.3,-5mm);
    \draw[fill=gray!40] (1.3,0) circle(2mm and 5mm);
    \end{scope}
    \draw[thick,-stealth] (-2,0) -- (a);
    \draw[thick] (-2,0) -- node[pos=0.75,fill,inner sep=2pt,circle,yscale=0.7](b){}(-2,5);
    \draw (a) to[bend left] (b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]